# How to assign a variable in inline for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which I am looping through with inline loop:

```
list = [{'information':{'num':1, 'name':'Helen', 'age':28}},
        {'information':{'num':2, 'name':'John', 'age':20}},
        {'information':{'num':3, 'name':'Jake', 'age':22}}]
```

So I want to do something like this:

```
loop = [(with person.information as per)
        {num:per.num, name:per.name, age=per.age}
        for person in mylist]
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way of renaming `person.information` object to per object?

My concern is that I don't want to write `person.information` every time.

Comment: Do you really only need to access `person['information']` twice? If so, it's probably not worth using a complicated workaround to avoid the second reference. You could shorten it slightly by assigning `info = 'information'` and set your loop variable to `p` instead of `person`. Then you'd just need to access `p[info][something]`, which is pretty terse. Or you could assign `info = lambda d, k: d['information'][k]`, then you'd just need to access `info(person, something)`, which is also pretty terse. Or use Pierre D's suggestion (that's what I do sometimes in this scenario).

Comment: I think the example changed from accessing just `num` and `name` to also accessing `age` at some point. If you actually need all the elements of `person['information']`, you could just use this: `[person['information'] for person in mylist]`. Also, @PierreD's solution does not loop over the list twice. It goes over it once, and each time it creates a one-item list with `person['information']`, then immediately assigns that one item to `per`. This is a useful pattern when you want to preprocess an item and then use the preprocessed version multiple times.

Comment: If you don't want all the elements in `person['information']`, there's also this option: `[{k: person['information'][k] for k in ['num', 'name']} for person in mylist]`

Comment: @MatthiasFripp there is no better way of doing it so yes that is the only way if i want to use inline loop. I am lazy to test the speed so i will leave it that way

Comment: @MatthiasFripp It looks painful actually. Pierre's answer is better i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trick I use sometimes is:

```py
[{'num': per.num, 'name': per.name, 'age': per.age}
 for person in mylist for per in [person.information]]
```

Note that this won't work with the initialization code you provided, as they are simple `dict` objects (no dot accessor). But if `person.information` was a `class` or a `namedtuple`, for example, then you could use it as is.

**Note about performance**

If you worry about that "fake loop" (the one that iterates over a 1-element list), it is interesting to observe what Python does by inspecting the disassembled code. Here is a toy example:

```py
import dis

def f0(mylist):
    return [
        p['foo']['a']
        for p in mylist
    ]

def f1(mylist):
    return [
        d['a']
        for p in mylist
        for d in [p['foo']]
    ]
```

Now compare the output of:

```py
>>> dis.dis(f0)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc886f6d710, file "<ipython-input-28-ebf24f3417d6>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f0.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (mylist)

  2           8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc886f6d710, file "<ipython-input-28-ebf24f3417d6>", line 2>:
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                16 (to 22)

  4           6 STORE_FAST               1 (p)

  3           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (p)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 ('foo')
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             16 BINARY_SUBSCR
             18 LIST_APPEND              2
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
```

with that of `f1`:

```py
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc886f6d870, file "<ipython-input-29-73fac11e7b55>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f1.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (mylist)

  2           8 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc886f6d870, file "<ipython-input-29-73fac11e7b55>", line 2>:
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                28 (to 34)

  4           6 STORE_FAST               1 (p)

  5           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (p)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 ('foo')
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             14 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             16 GET_ITER
        >>   18 FOR_ITER                12 (to 32)
             20 STORE_FAST               2 (d)

  3          22 LOAD_FAST                2 (d)
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             26 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 LIST_APPEND              3
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           18
        >>   32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   34 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the code for `f1` has only one `BUILD_LIST` (like `f0`). There is however a `BUILD_TUPLE` of a single element (`p['foo']`), a `GET_ITER` for that tuple and a `FOR_ITER`. These operations are all extremely fast, using builtin and fixed-sized objects.

Comment: This is a good answer, and doesn't have the performance problem that the OP mentioned. However, I don't know why OP and you are using dot notation. You can't access dictionary elements that way. Anyway, I mainly wanted to point out that newer versions of Python also have this option: `[{'num': (per := person['information'])['num'], 'name': per['name']}
for person in mylist]`.

Comment: @KyokoSasagava: please provide timing to support your assertion of "performance issues".

Comment: @MatthiasFripp: indeed (as noted), `dict` don't have dot accessor. At first I thought the OP had a `namedtuple`, then I saw the init code...

Comment: Also, @MatthiasFripp: good use of the walrus operator (`python>=3.8`). In this case, not entirely convinced by the visual elegance of the result, but it is certainly valid.

Comment: Thanks. That was inspired by the title, which asked about assigning a variable in an inline loop. But it's not very symmetrical or beautiful. I think I'd probably stick with your approach until `:=` is more widely used.

Comment: @PierreD I didn't test it but it is the same as writing this [{num:per.num, name:per.name, age=per.age} for per in [person.information for person in loop1]], Which is loping the same list twice.  I guess there is no way of renaming it actually. Thanks for answering anyways

Comment: @KyokoSasagava: I disagree, it's not the same at all. `[person.information for person in loop1]` would create a whole list, then iterate through that. The answer I provided has one "real loop" (`for person in mylist`) and, for each value, uses a "fake loop" (`for per in [person.information]`) which is much more optimized than you'd think. I just looked at the disassembly output for this code. There isn't a `BUILD_LIST` for the "fake list", only a single `GET_ITER`.

Comment: @PierreD You are right. I thought you are calling the main loop again. It is really useful. Thank you